# What is the total time frame on Google Apps Script DocumentProperties?

Tags: google-apps-script, properties, ttl

I am curious, I created a function that stores and reads data in a GAS property of DocumentPropertie. What is the total when using that property? is it an hour? 24 hours? One week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each key/value pair remains there until you change it.

There is also a Cache Service and that has a time threshold associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for that information, do you know where I can find any sort of documentation explaining the above?

Comment: Nope I don't.  But I have properties that haven't changed for years.

Comment: There's also no documentation to show you that the onEdit event object has and e.range.columnStart but yet it has had that property ever since I can remember.